# È bastato a/per...?

Tags: word-usage, verbs, grammar, prepositions

1a)Cosa è bastato a fargli cambiare idea?

1b)A fargli cambiare idea è bastato qualche esempio pratico.

2a)Cosa è bastato per fargli cambiare idea?

2b)Per fargli cambiare idea è bastato qualche esempio pratico.

Sono sicuro della correttezza grammaticale di *2a* e *2b*, mentre non saprei esprimermi sulla correttezza grammaticale di *1a* e *1b*?

Voi che ne pensate?
Un saluto a tutti .

Comment: Per curiosità, hai consultato la voce “bastare” di qualche dizionario affidabille, come il [Treccani](https://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/bastare) o il [GDLI](https://www.gdli.it/sala-lettura/vol-ii/2) (p. 97)?

Comment: @DaG Sì, purtroppo non ho trovato esempi per ciò che intendo, mi spiego: Se all'interno della frase il complemento di fine (introdotto da "a") è focalizzato/marcato, allora so per certo che tale preposizione si può utilizzare: "Questo a cosa è bastato?" "Questo è bastato a chiarire  tutto". Se invece è il soggetto quello ad essere marcato/focalizzato (su cui cade la tonica), allora su ciò non ho trovato esempi: "Cosa è bastato a fargli cambiare idea?"(???) "A fargli cambiare idea è bastato qualche esempio pratico"(???). Scusa se il messaggio è troppo lungo, ma spero tu abbia capito. Grazie.